# how to get top 2 values for specific year from a dataframe?

Tags: r

I would like to obtain the top 2 values for specific year, but the following code doesn't work:

```
library(tidyverse)
mpg
mpg %>% group_by(year, class, model) %>% summarize (n= n()) %>% top_n(2)
```

How can I modify my code?

Comment: use `slice_max()` instead on the column you want to extract top value

Comment: Try specifying the `dplyr` package directly for the `summarize` and `n` functions, i.e., `mpg %>% group_by(year, class, model) %>% dplyr::summarize(n= dplyr::n()) %>% top_n(2)`. R may get those functions confused with other functions of the same name but from other packages. I also read that [n() no longer works if dplyr not attached](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4062). My solution will solve that issue but I don't know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print and understand the "top n", it's better first to arrange your data in ascending or descending order according to n, but maybe your problem is that (it's not 100% clear in your question) you have to specify for which tuple you want top n, just top 2 by {year}, or by {year,class} ?

In your code you have top 2 for each {year, class} depending if dplyr ungroup the last grouping variable after summarise.

Another thing to consider is: if there are multiple car with same n value in the top 2, they all will be keepted by top n, not just the top 2.

By year like this with slice_max

```r
mpg %>% 
  group_by(year, class, model) %>% 
  summarize (n= n()) %>% 
  arrange(year, desc(n)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  slice_max(n, n = 2)
```

```
# Groups:   year [2]
   year class      model                   n
  <int> <chr>      <chr>               <int>
1  1999 minivan    caravan 2wd             6
2  1999 compact    jetta                   5
3  1999 pickup     f150 pickup 4wd         5
4  1999 subcompact civic                   5
5  2008 pickup     ram 1500 pickup 4wd     7
6  2008 suv        grand cherokee 4wd      6
```

Comment: Thanks!! I think I missed `group_by(year)` in my code. Now I figure out why that is needed.